# Counter should run indefinitely until Stop button is clicked which should return already set values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create number counters that will be in like 10 boxes counting individually. When the "Start Count" button is clicked, I want the counter in each of the circle to count indefinitely from 0 to 9 until the "Stop Count" button is clicked. When the "Stop Counter" button is clicked, I want to return the specified values in the HTML. For example, I want the number that would show in the boxes to be the set values (which are 785368 as shown in the HTML codes below).

With few helps, I have been able to create to the point in the attached pen. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JeByaQ

```js
  $("#startCount").on("click", function (evt) {

   $('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
      speed: 100,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
});
```

```css
#winh
{
  width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: red;
 -moz-border-radius: 50px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
 border-radius: 50px;
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
}
.count
{
  line-height: 100px;
  color:white;
  margin-left:30px;
  font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="winh"><span class="count">7</span></div>
<div id="winh"><span class="count">8</span></div>
<div id="winh"><span class="count">5</span></div>
<div id="winh"><span class="count">3</span></div>
<div id="winh"><span class="count">6</span></div>
<div id="winh"><span class="count">8</span></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

<button id="startCount">Start Count</button>
<button id="stopCount">Stop Count</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var num = document.getElementsByClassName("count"),
        speed = 1000,
        timing;
    counting = function () {
        timing = setInterval(controllers, speed)
    }
    function controllers() {
        for (n = 0; n < num.length; n++) {

            num[n].innerHTML = parseInt(num[n].innerHTML) + 1
            if (num[n].innerHTML == 10) {
                num[n].innerHTML = 0;
            }

        }
    }
    function stop() {
        clearInterval(timing)
    }
```

```css
      #winh {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: red;
            -moz-border-radius: 50px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
            border-radius: 50px;
            float: left;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        .count {
            line-height: 100px;
            color: white;
            margin-left: 30px;
            font-size: 25px;
        }
```

```html
 <div id="winh"><span class="count">7</span></div>
    <div id="winh"><span class="count">8</span></div>
    <div id="winh"><span class="count">5</span></div>
    <div id="winh"><span class="count">3</span></div>
    <div id="winh"><span class="count">6</span></div>
    <div id="winh"><span class="count">8</span></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <button id="startCount" onclick="counting()">Start Count</button>
    <button id="stopCount" onclick="stop()">Stop Count</button>
```

Comment: Thank for your response, but I want the counter in each of the circles to count from 0 to 9 indefinitely till the Stop Count button is clicked. When the Stop Count button is clicked the values in the 6 circles should show 7 8 5 3 6 8 respectively

Comment: I added this to the controllers function ` if (num[n].innerHTML == 10) {
                num[n].innerHTML = 0;
            }`

Comment: Thank you for the update @emmanuel-uchewa Instead of just pausing the count when the stop button is hit, is it possible to make the boxes show specified numbers when the stop count button is clicked?

Comment: I do not understand. specified numbers like

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var num = document.getElementsByClassName("count"),
            specifiedNumbers = [3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 3],
            speed = 1000,
            timing;
        counting = function () {
            timing = setInterval(controllers, speed)
        }
        function controllers() {
            for (n = 0; n < num.length; n++) {

                num[n].innerHTML = parseInt(num[n].innerHTML) + 1
                if (num[n].innerHTML == 10) {
                    num[n].innerHTML = 0;
                }

            }
        }
        function stop() {
            clearInterval(timing)
            specifiedNumbers.forEach((value, index) => {
                num[index].innerHTML = value
            })



        }
```

```css
   #winh {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: red;
            -moz-border-radius: 50px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
            border-radius: 50px;
            float: left;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        .count {
            line-height: 100px;
            color: white;
            margin-left: 30px;
            font-size: 25px;
        }
```

```html
 <div id="winh"><span class="count">7</span></div>
    <div id="winh"><span class="count">8</span></div>
    <div id="winh"><span class="count">5</span></div>
    <div id="winh"><span class="count">3</span></div>
    <div id="winh"><span class="count">6</span></div>
    <div id="winh"><span class="count">8</span></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <button id="startCount" onclick="counting()">Start Count</button>
    <button id="stopCount" onclick="stop()">Stop Count</button>
```

Comment: may be this is what you mean

Comment: I have posted an updated snippet that worked. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Emmanuel for your help so far. I was able to resolve the issue myself. Below is the updated snippet for anyone who might come across this.

```js
 var num = document.getElementsByClassName("count"),
        speed = 50,
        timing;
    counting = function () {
        timing = setInterval(controllers, speed)
    }
    function controllers() {
        for (n = 0; n < num.length; n++) {

            num[n].innerHTML = parseInt(num[n].innerHTML) + 1
            if (num[n].innerHTML == 10) {
                num[n].innerHTML = 0;
            }

        }
    }
    function stop() {
        clearInterval(timing);
        document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = "7";
        document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = "8";
        document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML = "3";
        document.getElementById("test4").innerHTML = "5";
        document.getElementById("test5").innerHTML = "0";
        document.getElementById("test6").innerHTML = "1";
    }
```

```css
#winh
{
  width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: red;
 -moz-border-radius: 50px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
 border-radius: 50px;
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
}
.count
{
  line-height: 100px;
  color:white;
  margin-left:30px;
  font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="winh">
  <span id="test1" class="count">0</span>
</div>
<div id="winh">
  <span id="test2" class="count">0</span>
</div>
<div id="winh">
  <span id="test3" class="count">0</span>
</div>
<div id="winh">
  <span id="test4" class="count">0</span>
</div>
<div id="winh">
  <span id="test5" class="count">0</span>
</div>
<div id="winh">
  <span id="test6" class="count">0</span>
</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>

<button id="startCount" onclick="counting()">Start Count</button>
<button id="stopCount" onclick="stop()">Stop Count</button>
```